# Is there a reason why only one coroutine works in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy which currently attacks all the time, with no stopping in between attacks. I want to make enemy wait amount of time before he attacks again to simulate enemy "resting" and giving player a chance to attack him while not attacking. I needed coroutine to finish my animation playing so it can go to idle animation while waiting:

```
IEnumerator Attacking()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animLenght);
        isAttacking = false;
    }
```

I have made another coroutine to wait for a second before enabling attacking again, but it doesen't work. Enemy attacks without brakes, like coroutine doesen't work:

```
IEnumerator WaitForAttack()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
```

I have put WaitForAttack() coroutine in my Attack function:

```
private void Attack()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitForAttack());
        isAttacking = true;
        StartCoroutine(Attacking());
    }
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong with coroutines, as I have just started using them, and this problem is troubling me for a very long time now.

Comment: `WaitForAttack` does literally nothing. There is only a return statement, so if you remove the call in `Attack` you'll understand why your code isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) says

> StartCoroutine function always returns immediately

So the `Attack` method will not wait after calling `StartCoroutine(WaitForAttack());` and set `isAttacking = true;` immediately. Instead, set `isAttacking` in the coroutine itself. Also do both in the same coroutine to ensure the operations are performed in sequence. Otherwise both coroutines will run at the same time in parallel.

```
IEnumerator WaitAndAttack()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    isAttacking = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(animLenght);
    isAttacking = false;
}

private void Attack()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndAttack());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't believe it was as simple as this. Need to invest more time into reading right documentation. Feels good to finally solve this problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am  pleased to help you and happy that it works, since I never programmed Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines can only suspend themselves (yield return ____) and not the method or object calling them. They are not the same as a synchronous method. When a coroutine is invoked and returns back to the parent method, that parent method will continue in the same frame.

In your method, you call "WaitForAttack()" and "Attacking()" from the same method on the same frame. "WaitForAttack()" literally does nothing.

Here's an example of a Coroutine that runs 5 separate times, once every second after it is called. Note that the var waitForSeconds is initialized once rather than every time I yield control back to the main thread. This is a minor optimization, but is considered best practice.

```
class TimedCoroutine : MonoBehaviour
{
    var waitForSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(1);
    IEnumerator CountdownToAction()
    {
        int countdown = 5;
        while(countdown >= 0)
        {
            print(countdown--);
            yield return waitForSeconds;
        }
        //Perform action here
    }
}
```

Comment: I now know more about coroutines thanks to you. I definitely have use from this code and knowledge. Thank you for your time.